# CSS - Two columns with different height - Stop scrolling down one column when end is reached

Tags: html, css

I have two columns created with css-flex. Now the content of one column is a lot more than the other column. When i scroll down this creates a lot of empty space to the left. I would like to scroll down and when the end of the shorter column is reached it should "stick" and just scroll down the longer column.

```
<div class="item-wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>

.item-wrapper {
  display: flex; flex-direction: row; justify-content: space-between; align-items: flex-start;
}

.item {
  width: 47.5%;
}

.item:first-child {
  background-color: red;
  height: 120vh;
}

.item:last-child {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 300vh;
}
```

Example: https://codepen.io/yabaikumo/pen/gOQrYbx

Comment: Go look into `position: sticky`. https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/, https://elad.medium.com/css-position-sticky-how-it-really-works-54cd01dc2d46

Comment: I use sticky but did you look at my example and check it?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about there now. Where in what you have shown us, did you try to apply sticky position?

Comment: You can check my codepen again, the scrolling behaviour with sticky is strange. It just scrolls to the end of the left element when its reaching the end of the right element.

Comment: Yes, the left element is "sticky" in relation to the scrolling container. _"and when the end of the shorter column is reached it should "stick" and just scroll down the longer column"_ - I don't think that exists in current CSS, you will have to resort to some JavaScript logic to implement that kind of behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Just add 'position: sticky' and 'top: 0' to every column.
Consider to add 'position: relative' to parent of columns.

Comment: That will make the small column stay in place while the larger column scrolls, up until the scrolling is the height difference of both columns, where the smaller column then starts to scroll with the large one, so both columns end at the same place at the bottom of the screen.